# Access denied to powershell.exe Start-Process from Jenkins descriptive pipeline

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am very new to Jenkins. I have installed it locally on my Windows 10, with no slaves, only the master agent.

Then I created the following declarative pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent any   
    stages {
        stage('Stage 1: Running TSextract') {
            steps {
                catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {  
                    powershell 'Start-Process -FilePath E:\\my-config\\bin2\\RemoteRunner.exe -ArgumentList "dummy.azurecr.io/my-extract:1.10.13 E:\\my-config test-79 -t td TSextract"'
                }
            }               
        }


    }
}
```

When I run this command in PowerShell from the command line everything happens as it should: Start-Process -FilePath E:\my-config\bin2\RemoteRunner.exe -ArgumentList "dummy.azurecr.io/my-extract:1.10.13 E:\my-config test-79 -t td TSextract"

However, through Jenkins, via the above descriptive pipeline, this results in the following error:

```
powershell.exe : Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: Access is denied.
At C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\LocalPipeline@tmp\durable-eb81f70f\powershellWrapper.ps1:3 char:1
+ & powershell -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Comm ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Start-Process :...cess is denied.    :String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
At C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\work
space\LocalPipeline@tmp\durable-eb81f70f\powershellScript.ps1:1 char:1
+ Start-Process -FilePath E:\my-config\bin2\RemoteRunner.exe -Argument ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOp 

   erationException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.C 

   ommands.StartProcessCommand
```

So the question is what/ how exactly do I grant permissions to Start-Process from Jenkins?